# Pyspark Job last few tasks hang

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Hi I ran into a strange issue with pyspark job and could not figure out what is happening.
Basically I have RDD converted from a data frame. I then use pipe() to invoke an external command to process the elements in the RDD one by one.
Everything works very well until at the end only 4 tasks will be left running and would never finish.
When I check the executor log looks like all records were already processed but for some reason the tasks did not exit.

Just wonder if anyone has any clues?

[image: Job Status]

[image]

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using python3.4 with spark 2.1

Comment: I got the same problem and this [askUbuntu issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907487/hanging-processes-after-upgrade-to-to-spark-2-1-0-on-aws-emr) describes the same. @seiya: Have you found out anything about it?

Comment: Actually the issue went away after we fixed an issue in the external program that it wrongly output tons of messages. We suspect it's related the the spark pipe buffer size but again we lack proof. Can't find any useful information from spark job logs. Strange.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and it looks like a deadlock. The threads of the executor are in state WAITING as shown in the thread dump:
[image: thread dump] and also the task time of the job is 0ms (meaning it hasn't even started!): [image: task time]

At the same time the driver process thinks the executor is actively running and is waiting for its results:
[image: actively doing something]
The last part can be checked by killing the whole job and checking the logs. For me the killing the job always interrupted `.toDF()` after a `mapPartitions(...)` saying something about `getResults`.

Actually seiya inspired me with his/her comment to come up with an idea. A full buffer could be the explanation for this behaviour and therefore I increased the values of buffer related Spark settings, i.e. `spark.shuffle.file.buffer=256k` and `spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=256m` which is four times their default value. Since I changed these settings the problem has not occurred for a while.